# Pyspark - Error when trying to iterate over an numpy array

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD with an ID as a key and numpy array as values.

For every value in the array I want to create another RDD that gives 1 for a value bigger than 0 and 0 for a value equal to 0.

I have tried to following code:

```
RDD2 = RDD1.foreach(lambda x: 1 if np.nditer(x) > 0 else 0)/
.map(lambda x: (x[0],(x[1])))
```

but it gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'map', and I am not sure why

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, this is how I ended up fixing it:

```
RDD2 = RDD1.mapValues(lambda y: map(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0, y))
```